# Scroll is loading lazily when i display captured images in android

Tags: android, camera

Hi when i loading the multiple captured images using below code scroll is scrolling very lazily,Before display images scroll is working fine my code is below can some one help me please

### code:-

```
     ContentValues values = new ContentValues(values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From your Camera");
                    imageUri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);

     @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            try {

                if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {

     Bitmap thumbnail = 
     MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(),imageUri);
     shopImageFile = new File(Utilities.getRealPathFromURI(imageUri,getActivity()));
     shop_image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use Glide/Fresco/Picasso when you load images from Capture images.
Because you are using Bitmap to show images those are not recycle do if you are using bitmap then recycle it using code.

Where Glide/Picasso is helpful to you to recycle your images and also helpful to cache image.

Please prefer below link hope this will help you:

Picasso : http://square.github.io/picasso/

Glide : https://bumptech.github.io/glide/

mPhotouri = content://saulmm.myapplication.android.fileprovider/my_images/JPEG_20171214_124759_1433289888.jpg

saulmm.myapplication == your applications package name. 
saulmm.myapplication.android.fileprovider == identify into provider as autority into ManifestFile.
my_images == my folder when i store images.

```
     Picasso.with(mContext).load(mPhotouri).into(iv_view);
```

this above is my in details code to you.
hope this helps you.

Comment: How to load captured images using Picasso?

Comment: shopImageFile = new File(Utilities.getRealPathFromURI(imageUri, getActivity()));
                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(shopImageFile)
                        .resize(96, 96).centerCrop().into(shop_image);

Comment: let me try and tell you result and small doubt "yourImagePath" means file path right?

Comment: please remove file:/// then check

Comment: Please check my latest updated answers and Upvote it because i already tested it and after update into this